# calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)}{x\cdot \arctan (\frac{x}{x^2 + (y-2)^2})}$

Tags: limits

I need to calculate the following limit$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)}{x\cdot \arctan(\frac{x}{x^2 + (y-2)^2})}$$ or prove that it doesn't exists. let $x_n, y_n$ be sequences $x_n\to 0, y_n\to2$. the sequence $\arctan(\frac{x_n}{x_n^2 + (y_n-2)^2})$ is bounded because $|\arctan x| \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$ hence $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)}{x\cdot \arctan(\frac{x}{x^2 + (y-2)^2})}=0$$ but when I tried to double check my answer using wolfram alpha I got that the limit doesn't exists

Comment: the limit of $\arctan(\frac{x}{x^+(y-2)^2}$ might change but in the end it's still bounded, and because $x_n\to0$ the limit should be 0

Comment: Your answer is correct. The limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this helps, but consider $C_{1} = {x^2 + (y-1)^2} = 1$ and $C_{2} = {x^2 + (y-3)^2} = 1$.
Both of them pass through $(0,2)$.
${x^2 + y^2 - 4y + 4}$ is the denominator that is required.
If you approach $(0,2)$ along $C_{1}$, then ${x^2 + y^2 - 4y + 4 = 4 - 2y}$ and if you approach $(0,2)$ along $C_{2}$, then ${x^2 + y^2 - 4y + 4 = 2y - 4}$.

So, then the limit becomes, $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)}{x\cdot \arctan(\frac{x}{4 - 2y})}$, for $C_{1}$ and $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)}{x\cdot \arctan(\frac{x}{2y - 4})}$, for $C_{2}$.

As you approach $(0,2)$, these two will have different signs.

Comment: they will have different signs but they would still become closer and closer to 0 because the x value does while the value of arctan, while it may differ in sign, will never exceed $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Yes, you are right.